# Regex replace on a limit

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a `LIMIT X` at the end of a string. Here is what I have right now:

```
>>> re.sub(r'limit\s{1,}(\d{1,})\s+?$', '20', 'select * from entity limit 1000\r\n', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'select * from entity limit 1000'
```

However, it doesn't seem like I've gotten the correct regex. What would be the correct regex here? Note that this could more easily be done by doing `str.split('limit')` and going from there, but for this question I need to use a regex.

Comment: What errors you are getting? Show them please

Comment: @JosuéCortina no errors, it just doesn't grab it. See updated question.

Comment: What??? It worked for me! I just copied & pasted your code into my console and it worked! Blowing mind

Comment: Same ... works here. What OS are you on, where did the code come from?

Comment: Side-note: `{1,}` is an unusual way to spell `+`, which you're using elsewhere. Odd to mix and match.

Comment: Yep, use `+` intead of `{1,}` and `*` instead of `{0,}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When asking for help, always remember to make clear what are you trying to do, [provide details](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html) and a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I'm assuming you have a set of queries and you want to remove the limit to have the queries return the complete result and you want to keep the whitespace at the end (this may be important in order to execute your query).

A working example I've tested in both python `2.7.15rc1` and `3.6.6`:

```
import re
query = 'select * from entity limit 1000\r\n'
regex = r'\s+limit\s+\d+(\s*)$'
replacement = '\\1'
re.sub(regex, replacement, query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The error in your regex is that you have the optional quantifier (`?`) behind another quantifier (`+`), but a quantifier needs to be preceded by an atom.

You can also replace the unneeded quantifiers `{1,}` for the equivalent form `+`.

The replacement I used in the example `\\1` is the group captured on the regex (the one between parentheses).

I've also added a mandatory whitespace delimiter before the instruction to make the result look more polished.

You can learn about regular expressions [for python3](https://www.diveinto.org/python3/regular-expressions.html) and [python2](http://www.renderx.com/files/demos/examples/diveintopython.pdf) (chapter 7).

Comment: `+?` or `*?` means `Non greedy` matching in regex. Sometimes it's necessary. -- fix typo, sorry about repeat comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\s+limit)\s+(\d+)\s+?$', r"\1 20" , 'select * from entity limit 1000\r\n', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'select * from entity limit 20\n'
```

Tested under 2.7.13 and 3.7.2 .
`\1` is to refrence the matched `" limit"` part, the `r` before `"\1 20"` is important.
Please leave comment if you still have problem.
(And please state your system & python version etc.)